# Using RxJava in Scala with flatmap

Tags: java, scala, observable, rx-java

I'm trying to use RX Java in a Scala app to execute multiple requests in parallel

The code in java that runs successfully is

```java
List<rx.Observable<Response<MyObject>>> observables = requests.stream().map(
    request -> client.getResponse(request).collect(Collectors.toList());

Observable<MyObject> mergedObservable = Observable.merge(observables)
    .flatMap(page -> {
        List<MyObject> objects = page.getResults();
        Observable<MyObject> objectsObservable =  Observable.from(objects);
        return objectsObservable;
}).toBlocking().getIterator()
```

I want to write the equivalent of this snippet in Scala and what I have is

```scala
val observables: Array[Observable[Response[MyObject]]] = requests.map(request => client.getResponse(request));
Observable.merge(observables.toList)
       .flatMap[Observable[MyObject]]((page: Response[MyObject]) => {
       val resutls: java.util.List[MyObject] = page.getResults
       val resultObservable: Observable[MyObject] = Observable.from(resutls)
       resultObservable
    }).toBlocking
      .getIterator
```

The code fails with the exception

```
 overloaded method value flatMap with alternatives:
  (x$1: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: com.mypackage.Response[com.mypackage.MyObject], _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$2: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: Throwable, _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$3: rx.functions.Func0[_ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$4: Int)rx.Observable[rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]] <and>
  (x$1: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: com.mypackage.Response[com.mypackage.MyObject], _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$2: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: Throwable, _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$3: rx.functions.Func0[_ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]])rx.Observable[rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]] <and>
  (x$1: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: com.mypackage.Response[com.mypackage.MyObject], _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]],x$2: Int)rx.Observable[rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]] <and>
  (x$1: rx.functions.Func1[_ >: com.mypackage.Response[com.mypackage.MyObject], _ <: rx.Observable[_ <: rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]])rx.Observable[rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject]]
 cannot be applied to (com.mypackage.Response[com.mypackage.MyObject] => rx.Observable[com.mypackage.MyObject])
```

Any thoughts on how to change the Scala code to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error says if you read carefully is that it expects to see something like `Func1[Response[MyObject], Observable[Observable[MyObject]]]`, because of the type parameter on `flatMap`. Removing it or changing to the correct `flatMap[MyObject]` may be enough to fix the problem (assuming you are on Scala 2.12 or on Scala 2.11 with `-Xexperimental`; otherwise you can't use a lambda directly for `Func` and will need a helper function).

If it isn't, I'd just extract the lambda and give it the desired type (still assuming Scala 2.12):

```
val f: Func1[Response[MyObject], Observable[MyObject]] = 
  page => Observable.from(page.getResults)

Observable.merge(observables.toList).flatMap(f).toBlocking.getIterator
```

You can do it inline as well:

```
.flatMap({ page =>
   val resutls: java.util.List[MyObject] = page.getResults
   val resultObservable: Observable[MyObject] = Observable.from(resutls)
   resultObservable
}: Func1[Response[MyObject], Observable[MyObject]])...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess i can help but just maybe. One time i have similar problem and the reason was scala firstly use scala.function instead of java.fucntion so lambda's are incompatible. I don't gonna promise that will work but use inner classes in place of lambda's.

Comment: thanks F0urth, can you clarify more ? How would you use inner class here

Comment: I mean I will replace this lambda's in map with anonymous class sorry for not being precise

Comment: Thanks, that did work. It can be an anonymous class or just a class like 

class ObservableMapper extends Func1[Response[MyObject], Observable[MyObject]] {
    override def call(page: Response[MyObject]): Observable[MyObject] = Observable.from(page.getResults)
  }

Comment: It's a solution, but it isn't necessary, you can use lambdas as well.